# Find the smallest value of $a+b^3$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers satisfying $ab=1$

Tags: contest-math

I am unsure as to where to go with this problem. Appreciate anyone who tries to help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The constraint means that $b=a^{-1}$, so you need to minimize $f(a)=a+a^{-3}$ on an appropriate domain.

Note: You are probably looking for a *local* minimum since $f(a)$ increases without bound as $a\to 0^+$ or $a\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$a=\frac{1}{b}$

Then we have to minimize: $\frac{1}{b}+b^3$

The derivative occurs at $\frac{3b^4-1}{b^2}$ The zeros of the derivative are located at $\frac{1}{3^{\frac{1}{4}}}$and the negative of that number (but we are dealing with positive numbers. So the minimum occurs if $b= \frac{1}{3^{\frac{1}{4}}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$1/b+b^3=3\cdot1/3b+b^3$$

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

$$\dfrac{k\cdot1/kb+b^3}{k+1}\ge\sqrt[k+1]{(1/k)^kb^{3-k}}=?$$

Set $k-3=0$ to make the right hand side a constant

Answer (score 0):

Since a , b are +ve  hence use $W.A.M\ge W.GM $  on a and $3b^3$ with weightages as 1, and $\frac{1}{3}$.
$$\frac{1.a+\frac{1}{3}(3b^3)}{1+\frac{1}{3}}\ge (a.(3b^3)^{\frac{1}{3}})^{\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{3})}}$$
$$\frac{a+b^3}{\frac{4}{3}}\ge (3^\frac{1}{3} a.b)^{\frac{3}{4}}$$
$$\therefore (a+b^3)\ge (\frac{4}{3})(3)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
Minimum of $(a+b^3)$ is $4.3^{-{\frac{3}{4}}}$

Answer (score 0):

The [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method can be used to find the local maxima and minima of a function subject to equality constraints:

$$g(a,b,\lambda)=a+b^3-\lambda(ab-1)$$

$\dfrac {\partial g }{\partial a}=1-\lambda b=0\tag1$

$\dfrac {\partial g }{\partial b}=3b^2-\lambda a =0\tag2$

$\dfrac {\partial g}{\partial \lambda}=ab-1=0\tag3$.

From (1), $\lambda=\dfrac1b$.  From (3), $a=\dfrac 1b$.  Then from (2), $3b^2-\dfrac1{b^2}=0$, so $3b^4=1$.

There is only one real positive $b$ solving that last equation; can you take it from there?